# Passing variable to htp.p in a PL/SQL Dynamic Content

Tags: html, oracle-apex

I am trying to pass a value in a variable for validation based on a db column and a checkbox on the UI component.
NOTE: Max_Set is the variable holding the maximum number from the DB column which is to be validated against the numberOfChecked items. However, when i pass Max_Set to the htp.p script, i am unable to use the value in the variable.

```
select num into Max_Set from table where column_name = name;

htp.p('<script type="text/javascript">');  
htp.p('function ValidateSelection1()  
{  
 var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("student");  
 var numberOfCheckedItems = 0; 
 var Max_num = Max_Set
  
for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)  
{  
    if(checkboxes[i].checked)  
        numberOfCheckedItems++;  
}  
if(numberOfCheckedItems > Max_num)  
{  
    alert("You cant select more than the required number for this SL Site!");  
    return false;  
}  
}');  
htp.p('</script>');
```

How can I use the value from Max_Set into htp.p script without it being considered as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pl/sql code, everything within the htp call is treated as a string. If you want to use variables that are declared in pl/sql, you can concatenate (||) to put it all together. I replaced the "Max_Set" with "l_max_set" to indicate that this is a local pl/sql variable and not a javascript variable and the initcap tends to make it look like javascript.

```
select num into l_max_set from table where column_name = name;

htp.p('<script type="text/javascript">');  
htp.p('function ValidateSelection1()  
{  
 var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("student");  
 var numberOfCheckedItems = 0; 
 var Max_num = '||l_max_set||';
  
for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)  
{  
    if(checkboxes[i].checked)  
        numberOfCheckedItems++;  
}  
if(numberOfCheckedItems > Max_num)  
{  
    alert("You cant select more than the required number for this SL Site!");  
    return false;  
}  
}');  
htp.p('</script>');
```

Comment: Thank you @Koen for your response. It is now working just fine.